# Vba closing excel applications/workbooks freezes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a problem with the following code:

```
Dim excelapp as object
set excelapp = CreateObject("excel.application")
dim ws as object
dim wb as Workbook

wb= excelapp.Workbooks.Open(path)
ws= wb.Sheets(1)
'in the code i send the worksheet object around by reference in order to read the
'worksheet and manipulate data, i dont create other instances of excel apps or
'workbooks
```

then i try :

```
wb.Close
```

and i have also tried :

```
excelapp.Quit
```

Neither have worked, they both freeze and say they are waiting on OLE actions, and i have multiple excel processes opening if i do not call these, when i try to open the excel files i had opened via code, i can only open them as read-only because theyre checked out to me.

I also tried executing a shell script that closes all applications "Excel.Exe" but it closes...the actual excel file where the vba is being executed, so thats not a good solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running this from excel? If Yes, there's no need to create an additional instance of Excel to open the other workbook.

Comment: Ok, so which object would i use? i tried APPLICATION but it opens the actual excel sheets, and when i try application.visible= false, the worksheet that has the button linked to my method becomes invisible. i have solved it by putting application.visible=true after, but it just looks kind of sloppy, was that the right way? thank you!

Comment: You can set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before opening the workbook, then set back to True when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the Excel app has detected that the workbook has changed and is putting up a dialog box (which is invisible because the app is not visible).  Try:

```
wb.Close False
```

Which tells Excel to ignore any changes to the workbook.

Comment: genious! ill try it, i assumed since it said that it was waiting for an OLE action, that it could have been something like a user response, but i had no idea had to make the app ignore it , ill try! thank you

Comment: It's usually worth making the excelapp.visible = true whilst you're debugging the thing - makes life a whole lot easier.  Also, define excelapp as Excel.Application and then Set excelapp = new Excel.Application.  Should make coding a bit easier due to intellitype.